# How do I get my shared disk back on line in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, samba

I have a folder on my disk which I share over the LAN so my wife can do backups to it. It has worked since I can remember. Now I've updated to 13.04 and suddenly I no longer see it or even my computer over the LAN.

I am referring to File (or Nautilus) where I press the Browse Network button. I used to see my own machine and hers, and of course the shared folder.

I tried to remove sharing from the file and then reshare it. I did a log out, log in but still no sign of my computer or the shared folder. I see her computer but not my own and of course she fails to see my computer as well.

I assume samba is working or I would have received a message when I did the reshare. The problem began after the upgrade to 13.04. Any suggestions?
Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that maybe samba was broken so I went into synaptic and completely removed it.

Just to be sure I did log out/log in after each critical step.

Then I reinstalled samba and if I remember correctly at this stage at least my computer reappeared when I hit Browse Network inside Nautilus (it may have appeared at a later stage).

The Sharing Options upon a right click was no longer available and the critical point here is to use synaptic to install nautilus-share. It probably was removed when I removed samba.

Finally I had a password problem in that I couldn't open the folder which I wanted to share to my wife. The point here is to use a terminal and type shares-admin. Unlock it and in the Users tab I saw my login user name, so I checked it and set my login password.

After that I was back on line. How it got broken in the first place is still a mystery, but at least my shared folder in now back on line.